# Spring Cloud Config Zookeeper Exception

Tags: apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to use Spring cloud config with zookeeper for configuration management.

My build.gradle looks like:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zookeeper-config')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server')
}
```

Here is my bootstrap.properties file:

```
spring.application.name = myapp
spring.cloud.zookeeper.connectString: localhost:2181
```

This is the application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
```

}

But the application fails to launch and gives an exception:

```
Error starting Tomcat context.
Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException.
Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar'
defined in class path resource
[org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]
: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]
: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint'
defined in class path
 resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]
: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]
: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
: Error creating bean with name 'configServerHealthIndicator'
defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/EnvironmentRepositoryConfiguration.class]
: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through
method 'configServerHealthIndicator' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.config.server.config.CompositeConfiguration'
: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setEnvironmentRepos' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
: Error creating bean with name
 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' defined in class path
 resource [org/springframework/cloud/config/server/config/DefaultRepositoryConfiguration.class]
: Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
: Failed to instantiate
 [org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository]
: Factory method 'defaultEnvironmentRepository' threw exception;
nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What could be the reason behind this? Seems like it is searching for git repository even after specifying zookeeper.

Comment: What version of spring cloud are you using?

Comment: @spencergibb from my gradle file :  springCloudVersion = 'Finchley.RC2'

Comment: We have an open issue here. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1051

Comment: Why are you using zookeeper config and config server together, seems odd to me.

Comment: ah! I think that was the problem, I tried after removing config server and it worked.